# Scala -Spark , selectExpr in Spark SQL for dynamic String with double quotes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark Scala for selectExpr is throwing  exception
-----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

> at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)

I am creating dynamic columns with cast for Struct fields  as

```
s+ """"cast("""+field._1)+" as "+field._2+""")","""
```

`field._1`  is current and `field._2` for new field.

I have printed the same and applied on the data set in spark shell the cast works fine. But from program it throws error

My expected output is

```
val fields= "cast(field1 as field_1)","cast( filed2 as field_2)"
```

Then apply this

```
df.selectExpr(fields)
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: What is `s` in the first code you posted?

Comment: Please provide complete code snippet. I can see multiple error and typos here. But I think your expression variable should be of type Seq. Eg. val fields= Seq("cast(field1 as int)","cast( field2 as int)")
    df.selectExpr(fields:_*).show()